# Prevent Gravity Forms Submission With Confirmation Box

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using the following code to output a confirmation box when the submit button of a WordPress Gravity Form is clicked:

```
$(".gform_wrapper.form-01 form").submit(function(event) {

    confirm('Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse.');

});
```

The popup works fine, but I need it to prevent the form submitting if the if the user clicks the 'Cancel' button. But regardless of which button is clicked in the confirmation, the form is submitted anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Managed to fix it myself (for once!)

```
$('.gform_wrapper.form-01 form input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var c = confirm('Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse.');

        if (c == true) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }

    });
```